Measurable of a vector-valued function
I am reading the Book of Stein,Singular integrals.
In page 45:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space.
Then a function $f(x)$, from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathcal{H}$ is measurable
if the scalar valued functions $(f(x),\phi)$ are measureable, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$
denotes the inner product of $\mathcal{H}$, and $\phi$ denotes an arbitrary vector of $\mathcal{H}$.

I have two questions:

Stein tell us if $f(x)$ is such a measurable function, then $|f(x)|$ is also measurable.  Why this is true. I know that $|f(x)| = (f(x),f(x))^{1/2}$. But I don't know how to use this.
Do this definition coincides with the normal definition of measurable (i.e., the preimage of any measurable set is measurable)?


What here is $x$? Is $f$ the function, or is $f(x)$ the function, dependent on some coefficient $x$?

https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1993-1123654-X. This might be useful.

I read this book 30 years ago. It's one of the most exciting books in real analysis.

@Gribouillis. It's fascinating. Thank you for your answer.

I think if the Hilbert space is separable, one can take a countable family $\varphi_n$ dense in the unit ball of $\cal H$, and one has
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| = \sup_{n} (f(x), \varphi_n)
\end{equation}
which is measurable as the upper bound of a countable family of measurable functions.
